# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in didDeselectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am absolutely new to IOS development and have got stuck on this one. I am trying a very simple thing here, I want that when I select a cell in my `TableView` it's background colour gets changed to grey and when I select another cell the background colour of the previous grey cell should be restored back to the default colour.

To achieve this I am using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{    
  let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RoundTableViewCell
  currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#d3d3d3")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
  let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoundTableViewCell  // Error
  currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ffffff")    
}
```

The above code works just fine but it crashes when I try to tap on a new cell while the previous selected cell is not visible in the table view as it is scrolled away. I can't understand what's happening here.

**Edit**

**cellForRowAt** :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{ 
   let cell: RoundTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as? RoundTableViewCell)!
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ffff     
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Could you show `cellForRow` method implementation? By the way, you don't need to do `as! RoundTableViewCell` in your case, just remove and everything should be fine.

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know.

Comment: Lookup the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow: An object representing a cell of the table, or **nil if the cell is not visible** ...

Comment: Always think twice before using a forced unwrap (!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if cell available or not

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
   if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoundTableViewCell  {
         currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ffffff")    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    ....
    ....
    if cell.isSelected == true {
       currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#d3d3d3")     
    }
    else {
       currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ffffff")
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

If you want multiple cell selection.

```
table.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

App crash because when cell disappear from screen its dealloc from memory so you get nil value. so try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{    
    if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoundTableViewCell  {
         currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#d3d3d3")    
     }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
   if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoundTableViewCell  {
         currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ffffff")    
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get expected result.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell


        cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIImageView()
        cell.backgroundView=UIImageView()

        let selectedBackground : UIImageView = cell.selectedBackgroundView as! UIImageView
        selectedBackground.image = UIImage.init(named:"selected.png");

        let backGround : UIImageView = cell.backgroundView as! UIImageView
        backGround.image = UIImage.init(named:"defaultimage.png");

        return cell


    }
```